# Sonar Issue-Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method. Return value from a method is dereferenced without a null check

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube

I have a void method which is being called with a string argument from a parent method.

```
private void sendMail(String msg) {
     SimpleMailMessage message = null;
     try {
        SimpleMailMessage templateMessage = mailSender.getSimpleMailMessage();
        if(templateMessage != null ) {
            message = new SimpleMailMessage(templateMessage);
            if(message != null) {
                if(templateMessage.getSubject() != null) {
                    message.setSubject(String.format(templateMessage.getSubject(), System.getProperty("env")));
                }
                if(templateMessage.getText() != null) {
                    message.setText(String.format(templateMessage.getText(), msg)); // This line of code is throwing Sonar issue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where you've used `getSubject` and `getText` without parentheses, is that a typo too?

Comment: No, I mean is `getSubject != null` supposed to be `getSubject() != null` and `getText != null` supposed to be `getText() != null`

Comment: You really should post code that you've already verified demonstrates the problem you're describing, not code that you've thought up and haven't even tried compiling.

Comment: Really? That does not sound like a good system you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String text = templateMessage.getText();
if (text != null) {
   message.setText(String.format(text, msg));
}
```

`getText` seems to be more than a simple getter. The second time it evidently may return null.

Comment: template.getMessage(); // what is "template" variable here ?

Comment: Sorry, answered on smartphone, mistyped.

Comment: Also if(message != null) is not needed. Constructors don't return null